# Как использовать браузер для скачивания html кода страницы?

Tags: python, браузер, requests

В python модуле requests  есть следующая конструкция:

```
r = requests.get("https://google.com")
r.text #получение html кода страницы
```

**Вопрос:**

Как осуществить это действие в python используя стандартный (или нет) браузер в системе?

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы использовал selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.page_source
```

Comment: кстати, с помощью selenium можно добиться того же результата без открытия окна браузера (типо как в консольном режиме), используя PhantomJS

Comment: @Bogdan  мне нравиться смотреть как скрипт "ходит" по страницам)